# Music isnt playing (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So i was using this Music Player https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py cause my own was too slow, it worked fine but yesterday i noticed that it didnt worked anymore, i used my own version of that so i just tried using the normal version, it didnt worked too any ideas why? Also sometimes stop or join doesnt work. Thank You!

```
import asyncio
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class MusicYT(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)

        await channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    async def sound(self, ctx, *, query):
        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {query}')

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.client.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def stream(self, ctx, *, url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.client.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def volume(self, ctx, volume: int):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("Not connected to a voice channel.")

        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = volume / 100
        await ctx.send(f"Changed volume to {volume}%")

    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @sound.before_invoke
    @play.before_invoke
    @stream.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(MusicYT(client))
```

Comment: Can you explain more about how it doesn't work? Do commands just not work at all? Does it just not play audio? and do you get any warnings or errors in the terminal?

Comment: It downloads the file but then doesnt play anything(no errors) @Lemon.py

Comment: Could you also include where you use `client.run()`? Remove your Token from the run command before adding it to your question. Also, I notice the `setup` function at the bottom is custom from the basic_voice.py, how are you running your bot? (what command)

Comment: i am running it in my main so i use cogs and im loading them like that

`initial_extensions = ["cogs.MusicYT"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(extension)
        print(f"Loaded {extension}")`

@Lemon.py

Comment: Using your code in my test setup seems to work without changing anything. The `join` command seems to be requiring a channel but if I just use `!play URL` it joins and plays the audio as expected. Do you have any error logging or try/except catches that are preventing errors from displaying?

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be that you have not installed voice support on your bot, I'm not sure but it should have mentioned installing a certain package;

```
-pip install discord.py[voice]
```

If you are using repl.it (in this case it is highly likely) then you have to constantly install it because there is no import command and repl.it doesn't actually install the packages, (or else with that many users, repl.it might crash) it just reads them. If you are going to be making a music bot I suggest getting a proper host.

In your situation, repl.it probably shut down while you were gone (or repl.it reboot) and the packages weren't installed therefore not working.

Hopefully, this answers your question, if you have any other questions, please ask away!

Comment: No, I dont use Repl.it i host the Bot myself, anyways i just tried on another device and it worked so it prob is a problem on my end. Could be ffmpeg not beeing installed right. Cause i alr have discord voice

Comment: What host do you use? I had an error regarding "ffmpeg not found" on a VPS, I would gladly help as it is package related. @Benflex